Why didn't the full logo appear?
I'm trying to add a logo to an object. The tutorials I watched instructed to export an Illustrator file as SVG. Then import it into Blender and shrink-wrap it to an object. I followed instructions (I think) but the white and grey parts of the logo aren't showing up even though the vectors for those objects are accessible in Blender. What did I do wrong? Is there a better way to do this?



Hello, maybe the faces are overlapping which creates Z-Fighting and black faces, but maybe share your file? Also if you plan to project a logo onto a surface, you could do it with a simple Image Texture node in your material?

You perhaps should consider masking the logo in as an inage-texture, rather than shrink-wrapping geometry?  eg https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/46447/35559

(Using Blender 3.6.8)
Two corrections are required from the original settings:
1. All three curves making the logo are using the same material (black, named "SVGMat.001"). A new material must be defined for the grey and the white parts.
2. As written by moonboots, all three filled curves are overlapping. The grey part must be shifted in X direction by a small amount (e.g. 0.001) while the white part must be shifted in X direction by a larger amount (e.g. 0.002).

Resources: 
